# How to properly connect a ReactJS component to Redux using react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I´m trying to build my first connection between a React component to Redux to gather data from my node API.

This is a simple component for now, but it will grow in the future and will derive subcomponents that will allow me to build a full User CRUD interface (list, edit, delete, view, etc.). In that sense, I need to connect the action functions to the object `this.props` so that it can be inheritated by the child components.

Here is my code:

**Component UserGrid - A table data grid that will load users information**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as userActions from '../../actions/userActions';

class UserGrid extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchUsers();
  }

  render() {
    const mappedUsers = users.map(user => <li>{user.email}</li>);
    return (
            <div>
              <ul>{mappedUsers}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    bindActionCreators(userActions, dispatch)
)(UserGrid);
```

**My `userAction`, that effectively will load users from an AJAX call:**

```js
import axios from "axios";

export function fetchUsers() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get("/api/users")
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_USERS_FULFILLED", payload: response.data});
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_USERS_REJECTED", payload: err});
      })
  }
}
```

With this code I´m getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:37984)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:37711)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:8466)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:556)
    at fn (bundle.js:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:588)
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:37984
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:556
fn @ bundle.js:87
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:37711
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:556
fn @ bundle.js:87
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:8466
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:556
fn @ bundle.js:87
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:588
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:556
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:579
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:582
```

What is the correct way to connect my component to the Redux services created?

Comment: You are passing `dispatch` as an argument to `bindActionCreators` but it isn't defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the component you wish to connect you need to define the function `mapDispatchToProps`. This function will take dispatch as a parameter, and will receive this parameter when connect calls the function.

Here is some example code pulled from one of my recent projects.

```
   function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            adminActions: bindActionCreators(adminOrdersActions, dispatch),
            schoolActions: bindActionCreators(schoolOrdersListActions, dispatch),
            userActions: bindActionCreators(userActions, dispatch)
        };
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AllOrders);
```

Now dispatch is defined.

EDIT: To clarify, doing this will now give you access to your actions with the following syntax. `this.props.actions.yourAction`, or whatever you called the actions in the `mapDispatchToProps`.

This is your code with my changes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as userActions from '../../actions/userActions';

class UserGrid extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props));

    //this.props.fetchUsers();
    this.props.actions.fetchUsers();
  }

  render() {

    const mappedUsers = users.map(user => <li>{user.email}</li>)

    return (
            <div>
            <ul>{mappedUsers}</ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    // this function will now give you access to all your useractions by simply calling this.props.actions.
    //if the key of this object would not be actions, but rather foobar, you will get your actions by 
    // calling this.props.foobar
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(userActions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    mapDispatchToProps
)(UserGrid);
```

Comment: Doing that I got the following error: `bindActionCreators expected an object or a function, instead received undefined. Did you write "import ActionCreators from" instead of "import * as ActionCreators from"?`

Comment: import * as is the way to go `import * as schoolOrdersListActions from '../actions/schoolOrdersListActions'; `

Comment: Now another error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.fetchUsers is not a function
    at UserGrid.componentWillMount (bundle.js:37951)`

Comment: this.props.actions.yourfunctioname

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchUsers' of undefined` with this.props.actions.fetchUsers. The actions are not being loaded.

Comment: right I am trying to make this clear, sadly I am failing. In mapdispatchtopprops you are returning an object where the keys are the names of your actions, So if you see in my example I have orderActions, so now I have access like this. this.props.orderActions.whatever. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: Not very clear. I can´t see `orderActions` in your code. The ideal way is the point the posted code (original) what shall be changed in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to use `bindActionCreators` here. Here's what [the docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html#somecomponentjs) say (emphasis mine):

> Normally you should just call `dispatch` directly on your `Store` instance. If you use Redux with React, react-redux will provide you with the `dispatch` function so you can call it directly, too.
>
> **The only use case for `bindActionCreators` is when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that isn't aware of Redux**, and you don't want to pass `dispatch` or the Redux store to it.

Since that's not what you're doing, you should instead call `dispatch` directly. With react-redux, `connect` will inject it into your props, so you can just do this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchUsers());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I´m aware, but I want to use `this.props.fetchUsers()` instead of `this.props.dispatch(fetchUsers())`. `UserGrid` is a now simple component but will grow and have subcomponents that will need to use the dispatch functions directly on their props.

Comment: Your question doesn't really express that. Could you edit it to more clearly demonstrate your use case?

Answer (score 1):

As [Jordan said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42209381/3276759) I would not use `bindActionCreators`.

Your component should look something like this:

```
import React  from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import myAction from './my-action';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.myAction();
    }

    render() {
        return "Hi!"
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    myState: state.myState
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    myAction: () => dispatch(myAction())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```